# Jquery each function (key, value) result only returns last key and value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each

1.Jquery each function (key, value) result only returns last key and value. 
2.It is working fine in an alert box 
3.while getting the data into HTML it returns only last key and value

```js
var result = '{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe","Email":"johndoe@johndoe.com","Phone":"123 dead drive"}';

$.each($.parseJSON(result), function(k, v) {
  console.log(k + ' is ' + v);
  $('#stage').html('<p>' + k +':' + v+ '</p>'); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="stage" style = "background-color:#cc0;">
   STAGE
</div>
```

I don't know how to get all values in HTML please help thanks in advance.

Comment: If you would, please post all the code relevant to the question *in the question itself* - don't hide it behind a link. You shouldn't tell potential helpers who would otherwise love to help that they have to navigate offsite just to have an idea of what you're working with. If the link breaks, the question could be rendered useless to future readers. Please edit your code into the question in a [MCVE], or the question might get closed, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use `.append()` instead of `.html()`

```js
var result = '{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe","Email":"johndoe@johndoe.com","Phone":"123 dead drive"}';

$.each($.parseJSON(result), function(k, v) {
  //console.log(k + ' is ' + v);
  $('#stage').append('<p>' + k + ':' + v + '</p>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="stage" style="background-color:#cc0;">
  STAGE
</div>
```

Comment: Your code hasn't good performance as you can see in [learn.jquery](https://learn.jquery.com/performance/append-outside-loop/)

Answer (score 1):

Because you rewrite html on `#stage` in every loop. You need to store content in variable and after end of loop, insert resutl into document.

```js
var result = '{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe","Email":"johndoe@johndoe.com","Phone":"123 dead drive"}';

var html = "";
$.each($.parseJSON(result), function(k, v) {
  html += '<p>' + k +':' + v+ '</p>';
});
$('#stage').html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="stage" style = "background-color:#cc0;">
   STAGE
</div>
```

Comment: @VenkateshSrikanth Glad to help you. Also check https://learn.jquery.com/performance/append-outside-loop/